# Generating public key with EC in Python

Tags: python, cryptography, jwt, x509, python-cryptography

I'm creating JWT parser and now I need to create public key. I made it in Kotlin. But now I have to create same parser in Python. But I got stuck in creating X.509 certificate in python. I tried with `cryptography` library but with no success. Code in Kotlin. Thanks for responses.

```
val factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC")
val publicSpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(key))
return factory.generatePublic(publicSpec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably combine [this tutorial](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/tutorial/#creating-a-self-signed-certificate) about generating a self-signed certificate and replacing the private key generation with [this material](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec/).

Key generation example with SECP384R1:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
key = ec.generate_private_key(
     ec.SECP384R1(), default_backend()
)
```

Comment: I tried this library but with no success.

Comment: @PatrikDendis Well, show your code so we can help

Comment: Thanks @Lou_is but I gave it up and I used generated public key from Kotlin and then just paste to Python.